# Why scipy.optimize.differential_evolution does not return last population?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, scipy-optimize, evolutionary-algorithm, differential-evolution

*Differential evolution* is population based algorithm. However, `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution` returns result as `OptimizeResult` which gives only the best elite of the population ignoring the rest of its generation.

How can someone preserve information about the last population?

Answer (score 1):

One way I found to return the last population is to download the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L22-L331)  and work with the class `DifferentialEvolutionSolver` directly:

```
solver = DifferentialEvolutionSolver(fun, bounds, arg**)
solver.init_population_random()
solver.__next__() # for each generation

last_pop = solver.population
las_pop_costs = solver.population_energies
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but bear in mind that the `DifferentialEvolutionSolver` class is private (you can't `from scipy.optimize import DifferentialEvolutionSolver`), so may be subject to change. E.g. the class may be renamed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to keep the trial population at each iteration using the ability of the `workers` keyword to accept a map-like `callable` that is sent the entire trial population and is expected to return an array with the function values evaluated for the entire trial population:

```
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
bounds=[(0, 10), (0, 10)]

# pop will retain the trial population at each iteration of the minimisation
pop = []
energies = []

def maplike_fun(func, x):
    # x.shape == (S, N), where S is the size of the population and N
    # is the number of parameters. The rosen function is vectorised,
    # so calling rosen with x.T will return an array of shape (S,)
    # you could also do:
    # v = np.array(list(map(func, x)))
    pop.append(np.copy(x))
    e = func(x.T)
    energies.append(e)
    return e

res = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, workers=maplike_fun, polish=False, updating='deferred')
# the initial evaluation of the population is not counted in the number
# of iterations, so pop[0] is the initial population.
assert res.nit == len(pop) - 1
```

To get the *actual* population at each iteration you then need to iterate through the list of trial populations and successively update `pop[0]`:

```
pop_up = [pop[0]]
energies_up = [energies[0]]
for i in range(1, len(pop)):
    new_energies = np.copy(energies_up[-1])
    new_pop = np.copy(pop_up[-1])

    pos = energies[i] < new_energies
    new_energies[pos] = energies[i][pos]
    new_pop[pos] = pop[i][pos]
    
    pop_up.append(new_pop)
    energies_up.append(new_energies)
```

The actual population evolution is then described by `pop_up`.

From scipy 1.9 there will also be a `vectorized` keyword, which will send the entire trial population to the objective function at each iteration.